# AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID not playing mp3 files

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, mp3, playback

Can anyone answer how to play mp3 files using `AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID()`? I tried but not working.

I have used the  following code snippet for playing mp3

```
NSURL *soundURL   = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:fileName withExtension:extension];

soundFileURLRef = (CFURLRef) [soundURL retain];

// Create a system sound object representing the sound file.
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID ( soundFileURLRef,&soundFileObject);
```

Comment: Can you show what have you tried?

Comment: NSURL *soundURL   = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:fileName withExtension:extension];

//filename and extension are given while calling the function.


soundFileURLRef = (CFURLRef) [soundURL retain];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID ( soundFileURLRef,&soundFileObject);

Comment: Please don't post code snippets in the comments section as they cannot be properly formatted and are completely unreadable. Go ahead and update your original question.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem using this example. Maybe your sound sample is to big/long.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"tap" ofType:@"aif"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)url, &mBeep);

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(mBeep);
```

It was not working because the audio file was to long. I tried with the sound from the apple example http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SysSound/Introduction/Intro.html "tap.aif" and it worked fine.